# Separating boxplots in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot

I have four different boxplots, and they overlap. How do I separate them in Python?

My code is here:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

plt.boxplot(x=group_a,
notch = True)

plt.boxplot(x=group_b,
notch = True)

plt.boxplot(x=group_c,
notch = True)

plt.boxplot(x=group_d,
notch = True)

plt.title('sales values')
plt.ylabel('number of sales')
```

Comment: dude I'm just asking how do i make my box plots not overlap

Comment: there are too many numbers in the sample for me to post and show you

Comment: You can call the function as `plt.boxplot(x=[group_a, group_b, group_c, group_d], notch=True)` to get separate boxes.  And add labels with `plt.xticks(range(1, 5), ['group_a', 'group_b', 'group_c', 'group_d'])`

Comment: THANKYOUUUUU so much